# Print multi-dimensional array from preg_match_all

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-parsing, echo, preg-match-all

Haven't been able to find a straight answer yet.. my array $sitematches:

```
if (preg_match('/<start>(.*?)<finish>/s', $source, $matches)) {
    if (preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $matches[1], $sitematches)); {
    print_r($sitematches);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <A HREF="http://site1.com">aaa</A>
            [1] => <A HREF="http://site2.com">bbb</A>
            [2] => <A HREF="http://site3.com">ccc</A>
            [3] => <A HREF="http://site4.com">ddd</A>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://site1.com
            [1] => http://site2.com
            [2] => http://site3.com
            [3] => http://site4.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
            [1] => bbb
            [2] => ccc
            [3] => ddd
        )

)
```

How can I output:

```
1 - aaa - http://site1.com
2 - bbb - http://site2.com
3 - ccc - http://site3.com
4 - ddd - http://site4.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibilty with foreach is:

```
foreach ($sitematches[1] as $key => $url)
   print "$key - {$sitematches[2][$key]} - $url\n";
```

But at least one direct array access is needed.

Comment: I don't know, but I think it's probable... Write your own microbenchmark ;-)

Comment: thanks for answering the question, should get you warmed up for something more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sitematches[0]); $i++)
    print "$i - {$sitematches[2][$i]} - {$sitematches[1][$i]}\n";
```

simply get the size (count($sitematches[0])) and then loop over the arrays.

Comment: works. Out of curiosity, is there any way to avoid the counting and use a: foreach($sitematches....

Comment: I've added another answer.